# Fuel SDK Python scope mismatch

Tags: marketing-cloud, fuel-sdk, python

I'm trying to use the Marketing Cloud FuelSDK with Python to retrieve data extensions. However, I'm getting this error regarding scopes, no matter what I seem to do. I created a server-to-server API app in Marketing Cloud and set the scope for Data Extension to Read.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

> Exception: Unable to validate App Keys(ClientID/ClientSecret)
> provided: {'error': 'scope_mismatch', 'error_description': "Your
> integration doesn't include this scope. Update the scopes of your
> integration in Marketing Cloud Installed Packages.", 'error_uri':
> 'https://developer.salesforce.com/docs'}

My Python code:

```
# Add a require statement to reference the Fuel SDK's functionality:
import FuelSDK

# Next, create an instance of the ET_Client class:
myClient = FuelSDK.ET_Client(
  False, True,
  {
    'clientid': 'xxx',
    'clientsecret': 'xxx',
    'defaultwsdl': 'https://webservice.exacttarget.com/etframework.wsdl',
    'baseapiurl': 'https://xxx.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/',
    'authenticationurl': 'https://xxx.auth.marketingcloudapis.com/',
    'soapendpoint': 'https://xxx.soap.marketingcloudapis.com/',
    'wsdl_file_local_loc': r'/tmp/ExactTargetWSDL.s6.xml',
    "scope": "data_extensions_read data_extensions_write"
  })

# Get all of the DataExtensions in an Account
print('>>> Get all of the DataExtensions in an Account')
de = FuelSDK.ET_DataExtension()
de.auth_stub = myClient
de.props = ["CustomerKey", "Name"]
getResponse = de.get()
print('Retrieve Status: ' + str(getResponse.status))
print('Code: ' + str(getResponse.code))
print('Message: ' + str(getResponse.message))
print('MoreResults: ' + str(getResponse.more_results))
print('RequestID: ' + str(getResponse.request_id))
print('Results Length: ' + str(len(getResponse.results)))
#print 'Results: ' + str(getResponse.results)
```

Comment: Give your package write access also and see if it resolves your error

Comment: It did. Thanks for helping me out!